# Change the Date format in the menu bar

Tags: macos, finder, menu-bar, system-settings, clock

Specifically, I would like to include the year for the menu bar date display and, even better, if I could change it to the iso format like YYYY-MM-DD.

I was able to change how it is displayed in the finder windows and other places, but the menu bar doesn't seem to care about that setting.

Is there a way to change the format of the menu bar date in macOS Ventura?